# typedef struct usage

Tags: c, typedef

I can't say I've used a lot of typedefs, but in Cocoa Touch, it's is a little confusing. Take for instance CoreGraphics' own definition for CGPoint:

```
struct CGPoint {
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

If I were to define this from what I've seen in books, go:

```
typedef struct {
    CGFloat x;
    CgFloat y;
} CGPoint;
```

and it seems to be working perfectly fine. So is there a difference in what these are doing, or are these doing the exact same thing?

Comment: BTW, Xcode doesn't define anything. Xcode is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE). Those `typedef`s are from the MacOS X or iOS headers. You should try to gain an understanding of the difference between the system and the tools you're using.

Comment: Fixed, this really isn't even remotely related to Xcode, **when you people learn that it's not Xcode that defines types, compiles your code and wipes your bottom?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's example is the same as doing this.

```
typedef struct CGPoint {
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
} CGPoint;
```

The difference is that in code with Apple's definition, you could define a variable as either `struct CGPoint` OR `CGPoint`.  In your typedef you have basically created a nameless struct, that you then call a CGPoint, rather than a struct named CGPoint that you also call a CGPoint.

Often you will see typedefs have the 'struct' part replaced with something like `CGPoint_t`

EDIT:  Consider the following.

```
typedef struct {
    List *next;  // <-- compiler error
} List;
```

Why?  Because the type 'List' isn't known to the compiler yet.

```
typedef struct List {
    struct List *next; // <-- works because you named your struct, and used that name here
} List;
```

If you do not name your struct, you cannot include itself (pointer) as a member.

Comment: Is there any specific advantage of giving a name to the struct before typedef?

Comment: Basically it is a convention.  There is only one example of when you NEED to name a struct (that I know of) and that is when the struct depends on itself.  I will update my answer to provide code.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! Glad to see there are people willing to be nice to noobs out there!

Answer (score 1):

In C language, struct names (called *tags*) live in their own namespace. `struct Foo` names a different thing than `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
   int smth;
};

int main() {
    struct Foo foo; // OK. note `struct`, it is required
    // Foo nope; // ERROR, no such type Foo
}
```

In C++, `struct Foo` and `Foo` are the same thing.

If one wants to use just `Foo`, like in C++ (and like our intuition is telling us!), they have to create a typedef named `Foo` for the `struct Foo` type. This is what Apple's definition of `CGPoint` is doing.

You can combine them both into one statement:

```
typedef struct Foo {
   int smth;
} Foo;
```

This is how those books advise you to do it.