# Why are there two names for a struct in this C code?

Tags: objective-c, c

Theres some sample code I have been working with from the book "Learning Core Audio" like so..

```
typedef struct MySineWavePlayer
{
  AudioUnit outputUnit;
  double startingFrameCount;
} MySineWavePlayer;
```

Why is "MySineWavePlayer" in this code twice?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462475/typedef-struct-usage or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110944/c-typedef-and-struct-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the first one is actually not needed in this case, the second one is for the `typedef` if you write this

```
struct MySineWavePlayer
{
  AudioUnit outputUnit;
  double startingFrameCount;
};
```

then you need to do something like this to declare an instance of struct

```
struct MySineWavePlayer mySineWavePlayer;
```

you can then do this

```
typedef struct MySineWavePlayer MySineWavePlayer;
```

and then the declaration would become

```
MySineWavePlayer mySineWavePlayer;
```

so the original one

```
typedef struct MySineWavePlayer
{
  AudioUnit outputUnit;
  double startingFrameCount;
} MySineWavePlayer;
```

is a combination if these.

And you could even do the `typedef` for an anonymous struct

```
typedef struct
{
  AudioUnit outputUnit;
  double startingFrameCount;
} MySineWavePlayer;
```

So short answer is first `MySineWavePlayer` is the name of the `struct` while the second is the name of the `typedef`d type.

Comment: Technically the first of the two is needed unless you are declaring an anonymous struct. If you want to manually code `struct S myStruct`, you can no longer do that.

Comment: True, but why to do the `typedef` then, if you want to code `struct S myS;` then no need for the `typedef`.

Comment: It would be non-sensical yes, but it would change one ability of the coder. The only actual example where it would be necessary is some old pre-C89 example I worked with a couple years back where it didn't like typedef'ed struct definitions like those above. </nitpick>

Answer (score 14):

This is a common question which is answered by explaining the difference between using typedef when defining a struct and not using typedef.

The common idiom is using both: `typedef struct X { int x; } X;`

They are different definitions. To make the discussion clearer I will split the sentence:

```
struct S { int x; };
typedef struct S S;
```

In the first line you are defining the identifier `S` within the struct name space (not in the C++ sense). You can use it and define variables or function arguments of the newly defined type by defining the type of the argument as `struct S`:

```
void f( struct S argument ); // struct is required here
```

The second line adds a type alias `S` in the global name space and thus allows you to just write:

```
void f( S argument ); // struct keyword no longer needed
```

Note that since both identifier name spaces are different, defining `S` both in the structs and global spaces is not an error, as it is not redefining the same identifier, but rather creating a different identifier in a different place.

To make the difference clearer:

```
typedef struct S { int x; } T;
void S() {} // correct
//void T() {} // error: symbol T already defined as an alias to 'struct S'
```

You can define a function with the same name of the struct as the identifiers are kept in different spaces, but you cannot define a function with the same name as a typedef as those identifiers collide.

In C++, it is slightly different as the rules to locate a symbol have changed subtly. C++ still keeps the two different identifier spaces, but unlike in C, when you only define the symbol within the class identifier space, you are not required to provide the struct/class keyword:

```
 // C++
 struct S { int x; }; // S defined as a class
 void f( S a ); // correct: struct is optional
```

What changes are the search rules, not where the identifiers are defined. The compiler will search the global identifier table and after `S` has not been found it will search for `S` within the class identifiers.

The code presented before behaves in the same way:

```
typedef struct S { int x; } T;
void S() {} // correct [*]
//void T() {} // error: symbol T already defined as an alias to 'struct S'
```

After the definition of the `S` function in the second line, the struct S cannot be resolved automatically by the compiler, and to create an object or define an argument of that type you must fall back to including the struct keyword:

```
// previous code here...
int main() {
    S(); 
    struct S s;
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1675446/edit)

Comment: who is asking about `c++`?

Comment: @iharob What c++? except for the c++ style comments, this is straight C - oops just saw the second half which explains c++ subtleties. never mind

Comment: @ArlieStephens if this was c++ the whole question would make no point since in c++ you don't need the `typedef`.

Comment: @iharob: The question was not about C++, that's right, but I think the different behaviour in C and C++ is worth explaining. The OP's question has been answered after all and the C++ part ist just extra information.